# How to send a POST request through telnet

Tags: http, batch-file, httprequest, telnet

I want to know how to send a POST request to a server (e.g. Google Search). I already know how to send a GET request,

For example:

```
GET http://www.google.com/
```

I tried doing it like this:

```
POST /wikipedia
```

or

```
POST wikipedia
```

or

```
POST
/wikipedia
```

or

```
POST Search: wikipedia
```

Anyone know how to send a POST request through telnet/cmd/batch?

Answer (score 19):

Of course you can, don't listen to npocmaka! Telnet just opens a TCP connection to a port in a server and does nothing else. So, if you send the right commands (in this case HTTP request commands) the server will respond OK.

An example of what you have to write is:

```
POST /path/script.cgi HTTP/1.0
From: frog@jmarshall.com
User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

home=Cosby&favorite+flavor=flies
<PRESS ENTER KEY>
```

I think that you have to end with a new line for the command to get send.

Answer (score 5):

telnet httpbin.org 80

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Connection: close
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 11

{"test":true}
```

Comment: Credit for reminder to type telnet and supply it with the url + port number.