# How to generate an HTTP POST request using Telnet?

Tags: http, post, request, telnet

Does anyone know how to add HTTP body parameters into a request? I've tried something like...

```
telnet xxxx.com 80
Trying 128.x.xxx.45...
Connected to xxxx.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
POST /webapps/methods/check-post HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{"id":"myid","color":"blue"}
```

But I got a '400 bad request' response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 31 Aug 2017 13:54:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 311
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxx.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Can anyone help me to set up a correct HTTP post request with parameters, using Telnet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST request through telnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147030/how-to-send-a-post-request-through-telnet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another empty line between the HTTP request header and HTTP request body.The parameter should be something like: `key1=value1&key2=value2`